# Python Pandas groupby 15Minutes on a column that is not the index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe with Transactions which have a trading_date, a delivery_date and a volume. the Trading_Date is the index.

```
    Trading_Date    Delivery_Date   Volume
01.01.2015 22:15    01.01.2015 23:00    15
01.01.2015 22:18    01.01.2015 23:00    10
01.01.2015 22:25    02.01.2015 00:30    5
01.01.2015 22:27    02.01.2015 00:30    20
05.01.2015 02:15    05.01.2015 04:45    13
...
```

I would like to sum the volume in 15-Minute chunks before the Delivery_Date.

Therefore I have created another column with the time-difference from Trading_Date to Delivery_Date.

```
df['help'] = df.index
df['Timediff'] =  df['help']- df['Delivery_Date']
```

How can I get sums of the 'Volume' for 15mins, 30mins, 45mins... before the delivery date?

I have tried with resample and groupby but These just seem to work with the index.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you are trying to do.  But you could use `set_index('Timediff')` if your only problem is the need to use resample on a non-index column.  Groupby can be used on non-index columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply JohnE.  I do not necessarily want to change the index.  How can I do this with groupby and arrive at 15Min-intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it like this:

```
    dfA['help'] = dfA.index
    dfA['Timediff'] =  dfA['help']- dfA['Delivery_Date']

    dfA['Timediff2'] = dfA['Timediff'].apply(lambda x: x / np.timedelta64(1,'m'))  # converts Timediff in minutely value


    dfA['Time15M'] = dfA['Timediff2']/15
    dfA['Time15M'] = dfA['Time15M'].apply(np.floor)  # round


    dfA = dfA.sort('Time15M')                  ## Sort Data by the new Date and hour column
    dfB = dfA.groupby(['Time15M']) ['Volume'].sum()

    print dfA.head()
```

Which gives the following result:

```
Timediff Volume
-15      522.9
-14      978.0
-13      621.1
-12      737.6
-11      767.9
-10      611.1
-9      1564.4
-8      1230.5
-7      1800.3
-6      9250.0
```

unfortunately not on a proper timestamp but good enough to do the Analysis.